# Implement initial vector (IV) in CBC mode by DES

Tags: c#, des, cbc-mode

I don't understand how to use the Initial Vector into the DES. I have read how the formula of the Initial Vector with CBC mode [Block cipher mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Initialization_vector_.28IV.29). How to implement my plaintext into the formula.
Can i have exemplified

> plaintext = COMPUTER, Binary = 01000011 01001111 01001101 01010000
>   01010101 01010100 01000101 01010010, hex = 43 4F 4D 50 55 54 45 52|
>   Key = ENCRYPTT, Binary = 01000101 01001110 01000011 01010010 01011001
>   01010000 01010100 01010100, hex = 45 4E 43 52 59 50 54 54

Thanks

**UPDATE :**

I have two DES Encrypt project. The first project uses a library and the second project  without a library. The first project using the library, using the CBC encryption mode and the second project without library and no encryption mode. Cipertext of encryption results in the first and second different program. the problem is what should I add to the second program that cipertext same result. How the addition of CBC mode on my second program without a library.

First Project Code with library :

```
DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
DES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
```

Second Project Code without library :

```
public void getAll_RL() 
{
            string proses = "";
            List<string> R = new List<string>();
            List<string> L = new List<string>();
            R.Add(txtR0.Text);
            R.Add(txtR1.Text);
            L.Add(txtL0.Text);
            L.Add(txtL1.Text);
            L.Add(txtR1.Text);
            for (int x = 2; x <= 16; x++)
            {
                txtProses.Text = string.Empty;
                string resultEks = string.Empty;
                cp.Table(R[x - 1], "E", ref resultEks); //Tabel Ekspansi
                string resultXOR = string.Empty;
                string subKey = (string)DGVSubKey.Rows[x - 1].Cells[1].Value;
                cp.XOR(resultEks, subKey, ref resultXOR);
                string resultSBOX = string.Empty;
                cp.SBOX(resultXOR, ref resultSBOX);
                string resultPBOX = string.Empty;
                cp.Table(resultSBOX, "PBOX", ref resultPBOX);
                string resultXOR2 = string.Empty;
                cp.XOR(resultPBOX, L[x - 1], ref resultXOR2);
                R.Add(resultXOR2);
                L.Add(resultXOR2);
            }
            txtL16.Text = L[16];
            txtR16.Text = R[16];
            txtRL16.Text = R[16] + L[16] ;
 }

public void getIP1() 
        {
            string RL16 = txtRL16.Text;
            if (RL16.Length == 64)
            {
                string result = string.Empty;
                cp.Table(RL16, "IP1", ref result);
                txtIP1.Text = result;
            }
        }

public void getHexResult() 
        {
            string IP1 = txtIP1.Text;
            if (IP1.Length == 64)
            {
                List<string> AllBinary = new List<string>();
                string Hex = string.Empty;
                string ResultHex = string.Empty;
                for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
                {
                    string string8 = IP1.Substring(8 * x, 8);
                   AllBinary.Add(string8);
                    string hex = Convert.ToInt64(AllBinary[x], 2).ToString("X");
                    Hex += hex + " ";
                }
                string[] hexSplit = Hex.TrimEnd().Split(' ');
                for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) 
                {
                    if (hexSplit[x].Length == 1)
                    {
                        ResultHex += "0" + hexSplit[x] +" ";
                    }
                    else 
                    { 
                        ResultHex += hexSplit[x] + " "; 
                    }
                }
                txtHexResult.Text = ResultHex.TrimEnd();
            } 
        }
```

Result Cipertext in hex :

> First Project : 2B B7 4F 52 A8 0E 9F 0F,
>   Second Project : A6 53 62 DD FD 25 A0 C5

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com)

Comment: In general the IV should be unpredictable to attackers for CBC mode. So you should use a secure random generator to generate the IV, and keep the IV with the ciphertext. There are different schemes, but using a static, predictable IV doesn't cut it.

Comment: @owlstead thanks for the explanation. I mean how the manual calculation if the initial vector (IV) encryption using CBC mode. IV I have set the same as the key for encryption. Can you explain the calculation?

Comment: The IV is public so it can never have the same value as the key. Normally the IV is a single block of pure random data which is XOR'ed with the plain text before encryption (the following vectors are the ciphertext blocks after encryption). If the IV is fully random then it has to be communicated with the party doing the decryption. Normally it is simply prefixed to the ciphertext (it is always precisely one block so it can be easily retrieved and subsequently skipped for decryption.

Comment: sorry @owlstead  . I am less likely to explain what I mean. IV was obtained at random. but the project that I created, IV obtained from the input of the key. I edited what I mean. Please to see what updates I can solve the problem and how it works encryption mode. Thanks in advance for your explanation

Comment: The very first thing you should do is write your code without using Strings. The only place where you would need a string is as input (which you then convert to the plaintext byte array asap) and possibly to view some things in hexadecimals. Encryption is performed on bits and bytes, *not* strings.

Comment: You're Right. Encryption operation only on bits and bytes, but I've tried it here http://des.online-domain-tools.com/ and it's true. What I have input and output exactly the same results with the results of the project outputs that I created. And the problem is how to add code to the CBC mode of operation of the second project that i created.